# Domino 9.01 FP 9, Java Agent compile property only goes up to Java 1.6

Tags: java, domino-designer-eclipse

I am working on a Domino Java agent, my designer IDE is 9.0.1 FP9.  When I'm in my agent, I open the "project properties" click on "Java Compiler".

I click on the Compiler Specific Level and it goes up to 1.6.

I want to compile to Java 1.8 which is what Feature Pack 9 is supposed to do, upgrade the JVM to 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to compile to Java 1.8 which is what Feature Pack 9 is supposed
>   to do, upgrade the JVM to 1.8.

Java 1.8 available only Server Side => Domino FP9, not Notes FP9.
Java 1.8 on Client Side may appear in the Feature Pack 10...